# How to resize a dynamically printed text in Raphael JS

Tags: jquery, resize, raphael

I already found how to drag objects with Raphael JS.

But now, I would like to know if it's possible to resize a dynamically printed text and to get the new Width / Height of this "object" with Raphael JS.

Here is a first view of what I would like to accomplish :

```
$(function() {
var R = Raphael("holder", 400, 400);
$("#typetext").keyup(function() {
    var textValue = $(this).val();
    R.clear();
    var c = R.print(100, 100, textValue, R.getFont("Arial"), 60).attr({
        fill: "#ff0000",
        cursor: "move"
    });
    var start = function() {
        this.odx = 0;
        this.ody = 0;
        this.animate({
            "fill-opacity": 0.2
        }, 500);
    },
        move = function(dx, dy) {
            this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
            this.odx = dx;
            this.ody = dy;
        },
        up = function() {
            this.animate({
                "fill-opacity": 1
            }, 500);
        };
    c.drag(move, start, up);
}); 
});​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ZuYcG/

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT : [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmkfs/) gives an idea of what I would need to do, but with printed text.

EDIT2 : A printed text is defined by a path in the SVG structure and it seems that it's not possible to get the width and the height of a path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to "reprint," as in feed different pixel-heights to the path generation routines that `print` uses.  If you're interested in keeping the text scaled within certain rational boundaries, though, you could get the path's bounding box and then scale it to make sure it falls within the width and height of your canvas.

```
var bbox = c.getBBox();
if ( bbox.x + bbox.width > $(R.canvas).width() )
{
    var scale = ( $(R.canvas).width() - bbox.x) / bbox.width;
    c.scale( scale, scale, bbox.x, bbox.y  );
}
```

Functionality demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/p8BcB/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin.
Is it normal that the scale affects the dragging speed?

Comment: The scale becomes a persistent part of the transformation matrix for the object.  Methinks you could compensate by adjusting your translation to account for the scaling, a la `this.translate(( dx - this.odx)/scale, (dy - this.ody)/scale)`;